# CSS3 - Making a simple click-dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, drop-down-menu

Can someone help me with the code for making the same dropdown as on this page?

http://uk.fjordblink.com/presentation/

I want to make the same thing, exactly the same thing.

So i get the CSS behind it, eg. `#PresentationContainer` `.Pointer` `.PointerContent`
However, i do not seem to be able to make the dropdown with a sliding down effect.

Also, i do not seem to be able to make the text and pictures to show in a drop down, when the box is clicked. Is there some php involed in this?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: no PHP is involved with this effect they are using JQuery `.slideDown()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the site is using Jquery to perform the interaction and animation. You could do something like this:

```
$('#button_id').on('click', clickButton);    
function clickButton()
{
  $(this).stop().slideToggle();
}
```

Where `button_id` is the id of the element on your page that the user will be clicking.

For more info on jquery slideToggle: http://api.jquery.com/slidetoggle/

Comment: This is the way to go. super easy and provides a nice default animation. 

@Buchow_PHP is there any benefit to using your version as opposed to the more terse 
$('#button_id').click(function() {
    $(this).stop().slideToggle();
});

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {

            $("#PresentationContainer h3").click(function() {

                // Check if this presentation is allready open?
                bIsOpen = $(".PointerContent", $(this).parent()).css("display") == "block";

                $("#PresentationContainer .PointerContent").slideUp();

                // Open the current pointer content
                if(! bIsOpen)
                {
                    $(".PointerContent", $(this).parent()).slideDown("fast");
                }

            });

            // Wrap all images in the lightbox area with an a tag
            $("#PresentationContainer .GalleryContainer img").each(function() {

                oLink = document.createElement("a");
                oLink.href = $(this).attr("src");

                if($(this).attr("title") != null)
                {
                    oLink.title = $(this).attr("title");
                }

                $(this).wrap(oLink);

            });

            $("#PresentationContainer a[rel='lightbox']").click(function(e) {

                $(".GalleryContainer a", $(this).parent()).lightBox( {
                    fixedNavigation: true,
                    imageLoading: "/static/lib/lightbox/images/lightbox-ico-loading.gif",
                    imageBtnClose: "/static/lib/lightbox/images/lightbox-btn-close.gif",
                    imageBtnPrev: "/static/lib/lightbox/images/lightbox-btn-prev.gif",
                    imageBtnNext: "/static/lib/lightbox/images/lightbox-btn-next.gif"
                } );

                $(".GalleryContainer a:first", $(this).parent()).trigger("click");

                e.preventDefault();

            });

        });
        </script>
```

this is the piece of code use for that effect , also add necessary jquery files for proper working

Answer (score 0):

jQuery! Link to a version of jquery and add code shown below

```
$('.yourClicker').click(function() { 
    $('.yourMenu').slideToggle(); 
    return false;
});
```

Where .yourClicker is the trigger for the click event and .yourMenu is the class of the element that you are collapsing and expanding. fiddle below:

http://jsfiddle.net/Davidicus/k4LG9/